# How to write a Typescript hasOwnProperty type guard that accepts any input?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is mostly just to learn how TS works. Here's 2 ways I can write a type guard for hasOwnProperty:

```
function hasOwnProperty<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Prop extends any,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  prop: Prop,
): prop is keyof Obj {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop as any);
}
```

Error: `Type 'keyof Obj' is not assignable to type 'Prop'.`

```
function hasOwnProperty<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Prop extends any,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  prop: Prop,
): obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop as any);
}
```

Error: `Type 'Prop' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.`

If I want `prop` to be `any`, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What is `ObjectOf` in your code?

Comment: Oh sorry changed it, it's `Record<string, any>`

Comment: Could you put an input and output for test? I have one solution but I want to test it with your input and output

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class (let say `Test`) and use it in this way `prop is keyof Test`

```
class Test{

}

function hasOwnProperty<
  Obj extends Record<string, any>,
  Prop extends any,
>(
  obj: Obj,
  prop: Prop,
): prop is keyof Test {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop as any);
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBvAsAKEwX05gZgK4B2wSAlgPbHQAWkA8gO7EAKATpQA7ztICeAHkzRoDAEYAraPAAeSeMQAmMAErxgldksHJ25YgHMANNDDF%20APmMjoHbjPmKVZizYyWAFLcpSAXGJS7qJcnFwB9lzuAJQBoQ7kMADW8PyU%20HCISNDoGKLs8EiE7DQSkhpIAHTxSJQCPJX0EMxsYbwClcBgICCevpKm8VxmMOb80QDcOHhYswBuYOzQ%20ACMAEzQALx0jCyR7fyeKGABAES0qaem4mdphKfYxqfip5MzmsQQlCDwlSCUhk8qzWkyAA)